# how to make a field disabled, greyed out

Tags: forms

I found the hide() function to make a form field hidden. Is there a similar function for making a field disabled or greyed out? I want it to display but not allow it to be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are looking for the `#disabled` property, eg the [Form API Reference Disabled Property](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#disabled) that...

> Disables (greys out) a form input element. Setting #disabled to TRUE results in user input being ignored, regardless of how the element is themed or whether JavaScript is used to change the control's attributes.